# APEX: Assigning a Map without a Key to a List

Tags: list, dictionary, salesforce, apex

Sorry for the newbie question.  Learning Apex here.  Been working on an issue for several hours and can't seem to needle it out.

I have a JSON that I need converted to a List...  the JSON is retrieved via an API.  The code is pretty simple, it is only a couple of lines.

The JSON looks like this:
`{"id":1,"abbreviation":"ATL","city":"Atlanta","conference":"East","division":"Southeast","full_name":"Atlanta Hawks","name":"Hawks"}`

And the code I am told to use to retrieve it looks like this:

`Map<String, Object> resultsMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(results.getBody());`

Based on the JSON provided, there does not appear to be a MAP key being assigned, so I have no idea how to get it so that I may assign it to a List...

I've already tried assigning it directly to a List, but I didn't get much success there either.

I've tried this already:

`List<Object> other = (List<Object>) results.get('');`

I've also tried this:
`List<Object> other = (List<Object>) results.keySet()[0];`

I'm sure it is something simple.  Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Correction to the last line.  results.get('')   Should read...  resultsMap.get('')

Comment: Alrighty...  figured out that the API is setting the keys to the value, instead of a key to an object.

Answer (score 1):

You cant convert the map to a list without an id. Alternatively why to convert it to List. Use the map itself. Below is a code example of how you can use it using your JSON response. For example, I want to insert this JSON response into the contact record, so I can map it using the MAP itself.:

@RestResource(urlMapping='/URIId/*')
global class OwneriCRM {

```
@HttpPut
global static String UpdateOwnerinfo(){
    RestRequest req= RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res= RestContext.response;
    res.addHeader('Content-type','application/JSON');
    Map<String,Object> responseresult=new Map<String,Object>();
    Map<String,Object> results= (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(req.requestBody.toString());
     List<contact> insertList = new List<contact>();
    
    for (String key : results.keySet()){
    System.debug(results.get(key));
    contact c= new contact();
    c.ContactField__C = results.get(id);
    c.ContactField1__C = results.get(city);
    c.ContactField2__C = results.get(conference);
    c.ContactField3__C = results.get(division);
    c.ContactField3__C = results.get(full_name);
    c.ContactField3__C = results.get(name);
    insertList.add(c);
    
    }
    if(!insertList.Isempty()){
        update insertList;
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your response...  I think I found something that is working for me for now.  I find your code interesting though and will probably use it in large degree also.  Here is a line of something I found...  
Team__c record = (Team__c)JSON.deserialize(getTeam(id).getBody(), Team__c.class);

Comment: btw...  I'm looking for an online tutor on this.  And would be interested in knowing if you or anyone else might be available.  Perhaps through an online tutoring site.

Comment: But if you dont have Id in JSON response , the probably your suggested way wont work...

Answer (score 0):

Question can be disregarded.  Not sure if there is a way to withdraw the question.

Question was based on the fact that previous APIs had been sent in the following format:

{"data": {"more stuff": "stuff"} }

And the map key was 'data' with a list.  In this scenario, the whole API was a list and the keys to the map were set in place with the actual values instead.